# Development of a thread braided around a cylinder - Strange relationship

Tags: geometry, education, solid-geometry

I have a cylinder (L is the length, D is the diameter) and a fiber braided around the cylinder; the angle between the fiber and the longitudinal axis of the cylinder is $\theta$. I have some difficult to understand how the triangle on the right (see the below figure please) has been built.

If I say that b is the fiber's length, who can tell me why the catheti are L and n$\pi$D?

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Think of unrolling the thread on a sticky plane surface, so that the thread adheres to the plane while the cylinder rolls. You'll get exactly that figure.

Comment: Hello @Aretino, I know that if I unroll the fiber, i'll get a segment; the problem are the geometrical features of the triangle.

Comment: At every turn the cylinder, while unrolling, travels a horizontal space $\pi D$. The unrolled fiber always keeps fixed its tilt angle $\theta$ with the vertical direction.

Comment: @Aretino thank you very much for your explanation.